# Значение "ку-ку" в стихотворении Агнии Барто "Ку-ку!"

Tags: значения

В стихотворении "Ку-ку!" Агнии Барто персонаж Серёжа часто нелепо врёт однокласникам. Чтобы отучить его от привычки врать, дети кричат ему "Ку-ку!", всякий раз когда он опять врёт. Основано ли это на каком-то известном смысле или принятом употреблении "ку-ку"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not how *ку-ку* is usually used.

*Ку-ку* is, obviously, onomatopoeic for the sound a cuckoo makes and is used to announce your presence (so as to not startle anyone who didn't notice you come in), to reveal your location (like in a game of blind man's buff, or *жмурки*), or to say someone's crazy.

There’s no established exclamation for when someone is lying, except for those of general disappointment (*тю, ну* and so forth).

However, this is a work of poetry, so the author needed one that would rhyme well and fit into the rhythm of the verse. *Ку-ку* is as good as any for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Слово «ку-ку» в своём [третьем значении](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%83) используется часто, чтобы обратить внимание собеседника. К примеру, во время игры в «прятки» ищущий может сказать «ку-ку», обнаружив прячущегося.

Похоже, в этом стихотворении дети говорят «ку-ку», давая понять Серёже, что его ложь раскрыта.

[Ещё пример](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=29788&p=35):

> Через полчаса красноармейцы вытащили из подвала магазина утопленника. Человек упал, должно быть, в подвал и захлебнулся в вине.
>
> Чубарьков подошел к трупу. Он взглянул и, узнав, покачал головой.
>
> — Ку-ку, — сказал комиссар.

Comment: Спасибо. Однако, это очевидно, зачем персонажи говорят "ку-ку" в стихотворении Агнии Барто. О её мотивах при выборе "ку-ку" как раз можно сказать "похоже", "наверно", "может быть". В третьем значении "ку-ку" означает "я здесь", какой-то интуитивно понятной относимости к сюжету стихотворения я не чувствую. Не могу сказать, что коммисарское "ку-ку" было не к месту, но что он имел ввиду, тоже не понимаю. Есть какое-то сходство между коммисаром и детьми. В их "ку-ку" выражается негативное отношение. Но такого значения нет в словарях....

Comment: The commissioner ironically says _ку-ку_ because he had a talk with the drowned man, a profiteer, earlier. The man claimed that he didn't have any property for sale, and at the very same moment a cuckoo clock that he was hiding in his sack made the cuckoo sound.

Comment: @yewgeniy "Ку-ку" означает "я заметил".

Answer (score -1):

Есть ещё одно значение слова "ку-ку": "сумасшедший". Пример: "ты совсем ку-ку?"

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: "Ку-ку" в значении "сумасшедший" -- это современный сленг. Во времена Агнии Барто выражение в таком значении не использовалось.

Comment: Стишок - катастрофа уже в самом лучшем толковании. Если предположить, что Барто вложила в уста детских персонажей намек на слабоумие другого детского персонажа... Надеюсь, это не так.